# Error Updating AccountContactRelation Record

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

Im receiving the following error when I try to update an AccountContactRelation (ACR) record through a LWC. Below is the Apex that I am using along with the error. We don't have any Approval Processes in our org. Does anyone know what might be causing this error?

```
@AuraEnabled
public static string saveACRWithRole(String jsonObject){
    
    String tmpStatus = 'Temp Status Message';

    oprCustomClass opr = (oprCustomClass) JSON.deserialize(jsonObject, oprCustomClass.class);

    AccountContactRelation acr = new AccountContactRelation(Id=opr.Id);
    acr.Roles = opr.roles + ';Tax Client';
    update acr; //Line 108 in Apex


    return tmpStatus;
}
```

Here is the error message:

> 13:12:45:458 EXCEPTION_THROWN [108]|System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 07k0300000137jsAAA; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, We can't save this record because the “Approval Process” process failed. Give your Salesforce admin these details. This record is currently in an approval process. A record can be in only one approval process at a time.

Comment: try doing a query on `ProcessInstance` to see if any records are marked in an Approval Process (that might have been left over from some previously deleted Approval Process

Comment: @cropredy - thanks for the response. There are 5 records in there and they all have a completion date and status of Approved or Rejected.